# PHP script not looking in includes folder

Tags: php, apache2, phpmailer, php-8.1

I have a new install. Ubuntu 22.04, Apache2, PHP 8.1 and I'm trying to use PHPMailer. My test page with phpinfo all looks good and shows the includes directory /usr/share/php. My form and script are in a subfolder of my document root and it loads fine. But when I fill out the form and the script starts it errors out unable to find PHPMailer. It's only looking in the subfolder the script is in, not the global includes directory. I don't want to put the mod in every form folder and I know it's supposed to work from the includes folder. Is this an Apache or php config issue? Or something I have to specify in the vhost?

Comment: Please share the code here.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How are you including PHPMailer? Is it just a `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer` or `new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer()` or similar, or are you actually using `include` and/or `require`? The former two won't search the shared include folder (as far as I know/remember), only the latter does, and it can't include path-like semantics (dot, slash) at the start, either.

Comment: What Chris said, and also are you using composer? It would help if you showed the actual error along with your code.

Comment: Without knowing your specific use-case, there really shouldn't be a need "to put the mod in every form folder", there are modern ways to solve that, although your system might not be setup for that. Composer is by far the most recommended way to manage external dependencies, and it is what PHPMailer recommends, too. If that's not an option for your system, I would still use it to install somewhere, and then in your include path have a file called `phpmailer-shared.php` that boots that specific copy of PHPMailer using the `vendor/autoload.php` file and can be included everywhere.

Comment: I found the issue early today. Thanks to bad/tired eyes, I wasn't seeing the leading dot so it was looking for ./usr...  Once i fixed that i was able to sort out the Ubuntu method of calling it from the libphp-phpmailer pkg autoload.php. I was able to get the script working with a few code corrections. The only thing I didn't sort out was PHPMailer:ParseAdresses but i only had a few recipients for this form so it wasn't that big an issue. My form is back online and my managers are happy 

Answer (score 0):

Just verifying and closing out with the answer
I found the issue early today. Thanks to bad/tired eyes, I wasn't seeing the leading dot so it was looking for ./usr... Once i fixed that i was able to sort out the Ubuntu method of calling it from the libphp-phpmailer pkg autoload.php. I was able to get the script working with a few code corrections. The only thing I didn't sort out was PHPMailer:ParseAdresses but i only had a few recipients for this form so it wasn't that big an issue. My form is back online and my managers are happy